# How do I return the type of the subclass from the parent?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

When calling a parent class' `new this()`, I'm having trouble figuring out how to return the type of the subclass, not the parent class.

In the example below, the code runs without errors, but `child.hi()` shows up as an error because `child` has type `Parent` and not `Child`.

```
class Parent {  
  static get() {
    return new this();
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  hi() {
    console.log('hi!');
  }

  static make() {
    const child = this.get();
    child.hi(); // <-- type error
  }
}

Child.make();
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3taAoHEaYaAlsNAOZJoAUAlFvtAJDJoCuCK0KSA7tDQALEhHoBuJgF9cM3KEgwAwiJAATaEgAeaVGpjxk6RjhH0TLYAHsUEKyCQA6EFYo0A5CICE7upJwyOEyExGTQALZgANZI5phMzNa2GMCqGgC8giIQjlS0fkw4qSTqjmYFAbK4uColao6RMRJAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by using a generic in the get method so that it will resolve the type correctly:

```
static get<T>(this: new () => T) {
    return new this();
}
```

After making this change, both Parent.get() and Child.get() should work as expected.

Comment: This is correct, but you likely want to declare it as `this: new(...args: any[]) => T` otherwise it will only succeed for subclasses that don't take declare constructor parameters: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=6&pln=7&pc=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gKGtCaYaAlsNAOZJoA8AKgHwAUaAFsRAFzQpIDu0jAJTQAvPWi1hOPHmRoArghTc+0VuyEBuXNAC+OgPQH8hEmUo0GzNpxX9GAOieJytsCgCeAbQC6wsRJShsayVIrKPPzqEFrBetj62KCQMADCbCAAJtBIAB5oqJkw8MjoWDrAAPYoBAjywGiVCIy5XLXEKORS+PIADkjNgprxeGxC5TLQVTWVIEgOIJXkjADkbACEK0M6iXgERKTQALZgANZI49Iy0wRTGdkiajYOFrGTwPcOY9t4+onpxCyDhO5y0QA

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else not familiar with how the `new () => T` part works, it's a way to refer to class types by their constructor: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics